# Show customized Mouse over on a bubble chart in Highchart JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a Bubble Chart made through HighChart JS Module. The bubble chart is normal and is doing what it's suppose to do, the only issue I have with it that I want a customized output on hovering on a data bubble.

Have a look at JSFiddle I created here :- http://jsfiddle.net/DUvQW/8/

If you mouse-over any bubble on a graph, it shows a floating bar with an output of something like:-

```
Mexico
(1354, 1352), Size: 1928)
```

What I am hoping that it gives me an output of :-

```
 Mexico
 (1354, 1352) 
 Year: 2000,
 Size: 1928)
```

P.S. As you can see in the values, I added the forth parameter already as an year.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactoring your series data to an array of objects:

```
    {
        name: 'South Korea',
        id: 6,
        argumentField: 'total6',
        valueField: 'perc6',
        sizeField: 'older6',
        tagField: 'tag6',
        visible: false,
        data: [
            {x:160, y:801, z:1955, year:2000},
            {x:433, y:1653, z:1910, year:2005},
            {x:614, y:1432, z:1918, year:2014},
            {x:724, y:372, z:1950, year:2004},
            {x:434, y:936, z:1920, year:2003}
        ]
    }
```

will make life much easier...

Then use a custom [tooltip](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter):

```
   tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            var t = this.series.name;
            t += '<br/> (' + this.x + ',' + this.y + ')';
            t += '<br/> Year: ' + this.point.year + ',';
            t += '<br/> Size: ' + this.point.z;
            return t;
        }
    },
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DUvQW/9/) (note, I only modified the data for South Korea).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is setup a custom [`tooltip`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip) using the [`formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter).